# How does Spring filter ApplicationEvents

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have been studying about event listeners in Spring and came across [ApplicationListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html)  interface. Which eanbles use of generics for example like this:

```
public class CStopEventHandler 
   implements ApplicationListener<ContextStoppedEvent>{

   public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
      System.out.println("ContextStoppedEvent Received");
   }
}
```

As generic types are erased at runtime how does event dispatcher know the type of `ApplicationListener` at the runtime? Does it inspect method signature using reflections or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The Spring (and, of course, entire Java) uses Reflection at runtime to determine `generic type` from provided class.

I our cases the application context scans beans for `ApplicationListener` implenetations and stores them all in the list.

When you raise an `ApplicationEvent` that list of `ApplicationListener`s is processed to determine the listeners for specific event type and they are stored in the cache for future optimization.

But before that your `ApplicationListener<?>` is wrapped to the `GenericApplicationListenerAdapter` to invoke its `supportsEventType` using generic type from provided `ApplicationListener`.

I think you want to know this method:

```
static Class<?> resolveDeclaredEventType(Class<?> listenerType) {
        return GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(listenerType, ApplicationListener.class);
    }
```

And use that `GenericTypeResolver` from your code anywhere when you need to know the `generic type` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

in most code bases the event listeners are stored in different containers, for example:

```
private List<ApplicationListener<ContextStoppedEvent>> contextStoppedEventListeners;
```

and

```
private List<ApplicationListener<OtherEvent>> otherEventListeners;
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring will use it's `SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster` to fetch the event listeners using the `getApplicationListeners(ApplicationEvent event)` method inherited from `AbtractApplicationEventMulticaster`. To see if a listener support the given event type it typically wraps the listener in a `GenericApplicationListenerAdapter` which provides `supportsEventType(Class<? extends ApplicationEvent> eventType)`, the method to test if the listeners generic type matches and the event is supported.